# find rows that share values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I have a pandas dataframe that look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['bob', 'time', 'jane', 'john', 'andy'], 'favefood': [['kfc', 'mcd', 'wendys'], ['mcd'], ['mcd', 'popeyes'], ['wendys', 'kfc'], ['tacobell', 'innout']]})
```

```
-------------------------------
name |         favefood
-------------------------------
bob  | ['kfc', 'mcd', 'wendys']
tim  | ['mcd']
jane | ['mcd', 'popeyes']
john | ['wendys', 'kfc']
andy | ['tacobell', 'innout']
```

For each person, I want to find out how many favefood's of other people overlap with their own. 
I.e., for each person I want to find out how many other people have a non-empty intersection with them.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
------------------------------
name |         overlap
------------------------------
bob  |            3
tim  |            2
jane |            2
john |            1
andy |            0
```

The problem is that I have about 2 million rows of data. The only way I can think of doing this would be through a nested for-loop - i.e. for each person, go through the entire dataframe to see what overlaps (this would be extremely inefficient). Would there be anyway to do this more efficiently using pandas notation? Thanks!

Comment: please post your data in a format that others can use to paste into their IDE, i.e as code

Comment: added a code snippet of a sample dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logic behind it

```
s=df['favefood'].explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
s.dot(s.T).ne(0).sum(axis=1)-1
Out[84]: 
0    3
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
df['overlap']=s.dot(s.T).ne(0).sum(axis=1)-1
```

Method from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
s=pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['favefood']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

s.dot(s.T).ne(0).sum(axis=1)-1

0    3
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `get_dummies`? Not bad at all!

Comment: `get_dummies` is so slick and powerful!

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge thank you man, you may want to see the sklearn method as well :-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S I'm simply a data analyst for day job as of now. That being said do you have any honorable mentions of beginner machine learning material to start with?

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge start with example always better than reading, you can check kaggle Titanic

Comment: @YOBEN_S thank you for your answer man- works very fast on my large dataset. cheers! :D